# How to get data from Excel spreadsheet to populate on Python

Tags: python, excel, extract

Introduced logic for program into ChatGPT to input 4-digit site name from spreadsheet column A which should then populate corresponding row of data range from B through Q.

I was expecting rows B - Q to populate after inputting the 4-digit number in column A

Comment: If you introduced logic for a program, wouldn't it be beneficial to share with us that logic so we can see exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: Good point @CDubyuh. Here is the logic: If financial institution ID (represented by 4-digit number) is in Excel spreadsheet, populate and print Site Name, IP address, Physical Address, City, State Zip (columns B through Q)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.